# Is linking libraries not as simple as specifying the path of the library and the path of the header files?

Tags: opengl, gcc, cygwin, dynamic-linking, glew

Context:

- cygwin-gcc as my terminal and compiler
- Trying to use OpenGL for my program and it requires GLEW extension to make it work. I chose to dynamically link my program to the required libraries.
- Downloaded, make installe'd, the glew libraries and header files.
- Put .dll files in usr/local/lib folder including the opengl32.dll which is originally from the system32 folder to test but still not working.
- Put header files in /usr/local/include folder

Problem:

- Getting underfined references to functions.

Input Command:

```
gcc -o TestGameBoy TestGameBoy.c -I/usr/local/include/GL -L/usr/local/lib -lglew32 -lglu32 -lopengl32
```

*Edit: -opengl32 changed to -lopengl32 but just a typo.*

Linking output error:

```
/tmp/cc0Qp34q.o: In function `initWindowComponents':
/cygdrive/d/DMG_Emulator/BGWindow.c:35: undefined reference to `glewExperimental'
/cygdrive/d/DMG_Emulator/BGWindow.c:36: undefined reference to `glewInit'
/cygdrive/d/DMG_Emulator/BGWindow.c:48: undefined reference to `glGenTextures'
/cygdrive/d/DMG_Emulator/BGWindow.c:50: undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
/cygdrive/d/DMG_Emulator/BGWindow.c:54: undefined reference to `glTexImage2D'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note: I didnt included the SDL part since it is already working. I managed to follow its argument list but somehow not working for glew.

Id like to believe that this is because the linker doesn't actually load the library into the ram. Soo it is unable to fill those necessary data for assembly calls to function's memory space which needs a defined memory address? I dont know Im mostly theorizing myself after I watch a video probably realted to my problem. But this does makes sense for me though somehow I couldnt make it work.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-lopengl32`?

Comment: I just retyped the command line but it is actually what is my input.

Comment: Does it work if you put `-lglew32 -lglu32 -lopengl32` before `TestGameBoy.c`?

Comment: Nope. But wait i think i need to download more libraries than what i thought is enough. I just read the glut header and it seem to require more libs

Answer (score 0):

***Never(!!!)*** touch anything that resides in `system32` or `SysWow64`! These are operating system resources and messing around with those will cause a lot of headache in the long run.

As for using (modern) OpenGL with Cygwin… that's kind of a PITA. You have this XWin/GLX wrapper sitting in between, so that programs written for X11 can be run inside the Cygwin X11 server. This in turn means that inside Cygwin you're dealing with *nix-ish OpenGL library names, i.e. `-lGL -lGLX -l…` (probably expects X libraries as well). Which also means that you can not talk directly to the native OpenGL implementation in a pure Cygwin environment.

There's (might be) an error in your linker invocation. It's generally `-l…` yet you have `-opengl32` there (dropped the `l`). However the linker should complain about every miswritten option or libraries specified, but it can not find.

I strongly suggest using MinGW/MSys2 instead of Cygwin which gives you truly native Windows API environment and makes things lots of easier. MSys2 uses the Pacman package manager (of Arch Linux) and is an all around pleasant to work with environment. It gives you all the *nix-ish dev tools (GCC / Clang, Shells, etc.) yet is native Win32.

Answer (score 0):

`opengl32.dll` is a shared lib, but not the import lib needed by the compiler. `opengl32.dll` also does not match the expected the shared library name in cygwin that is `cyg*.dll`

Install cygwin `libGLEW-devel` package. It will provide the correct GLEW import lib and the headers

The content is listed on
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libGLEW-devel/libGLEW-devel-1.13.0-1

```
2016-07-21 22:36     1018809 usr/include/GL/glew.h
2016-07-21 22:36       73140 usr/include/GL/glxew.h
2016-07-21 22:36           0 usr/lib/
2016-07-21 22:36     2106644 usr/lib/libGLEW.dll.a
2016-07-21 22:36     1667262 usr/lib/libGLEWmx.dll.a
2016-07-21 22:36           0 usr/lib/pkgconfig/
2016-07-21 22:36         222 usr/lib/pkgconfig/glew.pc
2016-07-21 22:36         233 usr/lib/pkgconfig/glewmx.pc
```

There is also a `glew` package `OpenGL Extension Wrangler demos` that you can use to test the proper installation.